# Location Permission Descriptions in InfoPlist.strings for Russian not being detected

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, info-plist

I'm currently adapting my app for different languages but I got stuck trying to show the Russian translation of the location permission description.

**I created the file "InfoPlist.strings", I localised it to Russian so now it is in to the folder "ru.Iproj" and I defined the "Application has localised display name" as "YES" in the info.plist file.**

ru.Iproj/InfoPlist.strings:

```
"NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "Ваше местоположение требуется для точных отчетов о проблемах и отображения покрытия сети.";
"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" = "Ваше местоположение требуется для точных отчетов о проблемах и отображения покрытия сети.";
"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "Ваше местоположение требуется для точных отчетов о проблемах и отображения покрытия сети.";
```

I in the same folder "ru.Iproj" there is the file "Localizable.strings" for the rest of the strings which is working as expected.

**Additionally I set the same for other languages as Spanish, Ukranian, Enligsh, Italian... And this worked for all of them without exception.**

I repeated the process lots of times and I even removed all the languages configurations of the project and started again from scratch but the **Location Permission Descriptions are still not being translated to Russian**

I really don't understand why Russian is not being detected just for the InfoPlist.strings file and I really don't know what else I can try. So please, do you know what could be going wrong here? Maybe an internal method is wrong, or the language is bug...

Comment: Might be dumb question. How do you actually test this? Are you sure you have set Device language to Russian?

Comment: Yes of course, I did. How would I test it otherwise?
I also remove and reinstall the app int he case some data was remaining in cache

Comment: Please check the file permissions of Russian infoPlist.strings in folder structure. Do you see any anomaly there?

Comment: No anomalies, it has the same permissions as other languages (Read & Write)

Comment: Please check the package content as well. check whether ru.lproj files are available inside the packages.

Comment: What do you mean with "whether ru.lproj files are available inside the packages" the  ru.Iproj files are at exactly the same level as the other languages. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Packages in the sense, your ipa or app or archive

Comment: Hold on, the ipa is a binary, how am I going to open and check "whether ru.lproj files are available inside the packages".
I'm confused

Comment: Rename the ipa to zip and extract it. Then inside payload folder, right click the application and see the package contents. Hope it helps